# How can I interpolate a variable into a path without using eval()?

Tags: javascript

```js
const ob = {user: {name: 'Jane', extension: '1234'}};
const param = 'name';
const path = `ob.user.${param}`;
console.log(path);
```

So this prints "ob.user.name". What I want is for it to print "Jane". I can do that if I call `eval()` on `path`, but I'm told that `eval()` is slow, insecure, and possibly carcinogenic.

How can I interpolate a value into `path` and get to the value to which `path` refers without using `eval()`?

(The code in question will be going inside a React component, which I think precludes any solutions the window object.)

Comment: would `ob.user[param]` do the trick ?

Comment: *"...I'm told that `eval()` is slow, insecure, and possibly carcinogenic."* **LOL**

Comment: Using [Alnitak's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6491621/157247) to the linked question: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/mgpxzws9/

Comment: How's this for an approach? https://jsfiddle.net/tj4ke8hg/ @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @weegee - If you don't need a **string** path, don't use one. More: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable I assumed you needed to use a string *path*, not just a string *name*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access object properties using "array notation" too:

```
const ob = {user: {name: 'Jane', extension: '1234'}};
const param = 'name';
const path = ob.user[param];
console.log(path); // Outputs "Jane"
```

Comment: Obvious duplicates don't need answers, they need close votes and comments where appropriate.

Comment: Agreed. I imagine it got flagged just as i did drop an answer in. Definite duplicate.